# Laravel authenticated dynamic subdomain routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to get authenticated subdomain routing working for some specific variable subdomains:

```
app.example.com
staging.app.example.com
testing.app.example.com
```

These should be guarded by the auth middleware. They all essentially reference `app.example.com` but for different environments.

Everything that hits these domains should go to the guest routes:

```
example.com
staging.example.com
testing.example.com
```

This is what I've tried so far...

Created this middleware to prevent the subdomain parameter from messing up other routes and to allow successful authentication to redirect to `app.example.com`:

```
class Subdomain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = $request->route();
        $subdomain = $route->parameter('subdomain');

        if (!empty($subdomain) && preg_match('/^(staging|testing)\.(app.\)?/', $subdomain, $m)) {
            \Session::put('subdomain', $m[1]);
        }

        $route->forgetParameter('subdomain');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Added this to Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'subdomain' => \App\Http\Middleware\Subdomain::class,
];
```

Contents of routes.php:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain?}example.com', 'middleware' => 'subdomain'], function () {
    // Backend routes
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Controller@dashboard']);

        // ...various other backend routes...
    });

    // Frontend routes
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('frontend');
    });
});
```

When I access any route, I can trace that nothing hits the `subdomain` middleware...it just routes to the 404 page.

How would I make this work in Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the goal of my setup was to allow handling certain subdomain groups with optional environment prefixes, I handled it in the following way.

I dropped the `Subdomain` class as being unnecessary.

I added this to the `.env` file so that each environment can have it's own domain so the local dev server still works independent of the staging and production server:

```
APP_DOMAIN=example.dev
```

On production and staging it would simply be:

```
APP_DOMAIN=example.com
```

Within `config/app.php` I added:

```
'domain' => env('APP_DOMAIN', null),
```

I added these methods to `\App\Http\Controllers\Controller`:

```
public static function getAppDomain()
{
      return (!in_array(\App::environment(), ['local', 'production']) ? \App::environment() . '.' : '') . 'app.' . config('app.domain');
}

public static function getAppUrl($path = '', $secure = false)
{
    return ($secure ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . static::getAppDomain() . ($path ? '/' . $path : '');
}
```

Within `Auth\AuthController.php` I added this to handle redirects to the `app.example.com` from `example.com` even if prefixed with `staging` or `testing`:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (\Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->intended(static::getAppUrl())->getTargetUrl();
    } else {
        return $this->redirectTo;
    }
}
```

New contents of routes.php:

```
// Backend routes
Route::group(['domain' => Controller::getAppDomain(), 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
      Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Controller@dashboard']);

      // ...various other backend routes...
});

// Frontend routes
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('frontend');
});
```

Hope this helps if anyone tries similar!